# Show title of news in destination page url in ASP.NET Core Razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, href, razor-pages

i use this code to make a href link for show my news site

```
<a asp-page="ShowNews" asp-route-Id="@item.NewsID">
```

and finally in my adress bar get this adress:

https://localhost:44390/ShowNews?Id=33

but i want get values in address bar like this:

https://localhost:44390/ShowNews/myTitleNews

or

https://localhost:44390/myTitleNews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the route parameter from Id to the Title.

```
<a asp-page="ShowNews" asp-route-title="@item. Title">
```

Then in the ShowNews page's OnGet method, according to the title to find the News. The could as below:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string? title)
    {
        if (title == null || _context.NewsModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var newsmodel = await _context.NewsModel.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Title== title);
        if (newsmodel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            NewsModel = newsmodel;
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

And in the ShowNews.chstml page, set the `@page` directive like this:

```
@page "/news/ShowNews/{title}"
```

The output as below:

[image]