# How to display the title instead of the ID in URL in Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web, routes, razor-pages

How can I use the title instead of displaying the ID at the end of the URL?

I have developed a website using .NET 6 and Razor Page. In this website, there is a blog section which can be accessed by clicking on it to display a list of articles. By selecting an article, the details of the article can be displayed using the ID address of the article. Consider the following URL: https://localhost:44398/blog-details/4 The number 4 indicates an article with ID 4. According to SEO principles, I would prefer to display the title in the URL instead of the ID address. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: do you use two links?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73523734/10193401 or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174820/how-to-add-page-title-in-url-in-asp-net-mvc-url-generation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would prefer to display the title in the URL instead of the ID
> address.

Below is a demo, you can refer to it, hope it can help you.

In Index.cshtml, use `asp-route-title`:

```
<a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-title="@item.title">Details</a>
```

In your Details.cshtml.cs add title parameter:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string title)
        {...}
```

result:

[image]